# Absolute urls, relative urls, and...?

Tags: url, terminology, relative-url

I am writing some documentation and I have a little vocabulary problem:

1. `http://www.example.com/en/public/img/logo.gif` is called an "absolute" url, right?
2. `../../public/img/logo.gif` is called a "relative" url, right?
3. so how do you call this: `/en/public/img/logo.gif` ?

Is it also considered an "absolute url", although without the protocol and domain parts?

Or is it considered a relative url, but relative to the root of the domain?

I googled a bit and some people categorize this as absolute, and others as relative.

What should I call it? A "semi-absolute url"? Or "semi-relative"? Is there another word?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Here are the URL components:

```
http://www.example.com/en/public/img/logo.gif
\__/   \_____________/\_____________________/
 #1     #2             #3
```

1. scheme/protocol
2. host
3. path

A *URL* is called an *absolute URL* if it begins with the scheme and scheme specific part (here `//` after `http:`). Anything else is a *relative URL*.

A *URL path* is called an *absolute URL path* if it begins with a `/`. Any other *URL path* is called a *relative URL path*.

Thus:

- `http://www.example.com/en/public/img/logo.gif` is a *absolute URL*,
- `../../public/img/logo.gif` is a *relative URL* with a *relative URL path* and
- `/en/public/img/logo.gif` is a *relative URL* with an *absolute URL path*.

---

*Note: The current definition of **URI** ([RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)) is different from the old **URL** definition ([RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738) and [RFC 1808](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1808)).*

The three examples with URI terms:

- `http://www.example.com/en/public/img/logo.gif` is a *URI*,
- `../../public/img/logo.gif` is a *relative reference* with just a *relative path* and
- `/en/public/img/logo.gif` is a *relative reference* with just an *absolute path*.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood that properly. Does that mean `//yolo.com` is considered an absolute url?

Comment: @srph No. Only if it begins with the protocol/scheme it’s considered absolute.

Comment: But the browser seems to parse it properly. For example, `//yolo.com` would prepend the current scheme of the page. Is there any specific term, rfc, or reason why urls in browsers are parsed as absolute when prepended with `//`?

Comment: @srph Relative URLs are always resolved to absolute ones based on the context they are used in. Have a look at the [section 5 of RFC 3986: *Reference Resolution*](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-5) for additional information.

Comment: Nice answer, but who, in everyday conversation (or user-friendly documentation), is going to always refer to it as 'a relative reference with an absolute path'? MDN is usually a reliable source, but [they call it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#examples_of_absolute_urls) an 'absolute URL' with an 'implicit domain name', which is even worse. For as long as I can remember, these were called *root-relative* links. The meaning is clear (it's relative to the root), and it's so much easier to say.

Comment: The actual language used by RFC 3986 is slightly different: `A relative reference that begins with two slash characters is termed a network-path reference; such references are rarely used.  A relative reference that begins with a single slash character is termed an absolute-path reference.  A relative reference that does not begin with a slash character is termed a relative-path reference.`

Answer (score 8):

I have seen it called a *root relative URL*.

Comment: Amazed that this answer got just one vote in over 11 years! If I were writing user-friendly documentation, that's *exactly* what I'd be calling it.

Answer (score 2):

From the Microsoft's documentation about  [Absolute and Relative URLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676525%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> A URL specifies the location of a target stored on a local or networked computer. The target can be a file, directory, HTML page, image, program, and so on.
>
> An *absolute URL* contains all the information necessary to locate a resource.
>
> A *relative URL* locates a resource using an absolute URL as a starting point. In effect, the "complete URL" of the target is specified by concatenating the absolute and relative URLs.
>
> An *absolute URL* uses the following format: *scheme://server/path/resource*
>
> A relative URL typically consists only of the *path*, and optionally, the *resource*, but no *scheme* or *server*. The following tables define the individual parts of the complete URL format.
>
> - ***scheme*** - Specifies how the *resource* is to be accessed.
> - ***server*** - Specifies the name of the computer where the *resource* is located.
> - ***path*** - Specifies the sequence of directories leading to the target. If *resource* is omitted, the target is the last directory in *path*.
> - ***resource*** - If included, *resource* is the target, and is typically the name of a file. It may be a *simple file*, containing a single binary stream of bytes, or a *structured document*, containing one or more storages and binary streams of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

It is sometimes called a virtual url, for example in SSI:

```
<!--#include virtual = "/lib/functions.js" -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind just how many segments of the URL can be omited, making them relative (note: its all of them, just about). These are all valid URLs:

- `http://example.com/bar?baz`
- `?qoo=qalue`
- `/bar2`
- `dat/sly`
- `//auth.example.com` (most people are surprised by this one! Will use http or https, depending on the current resource)
- `#anchor`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are two types of relative URLs: relative URLs with a relative path and relative URLs with an absolute path.

(1) Relative URL with relative path = relative to the current page's URL. Files or resources that need to be linked are located within the same website.

Example, you are on `https://example.com/items/menu.html`.

You want to link to an image file in the `images` folder in the same directory as the current page, you would use the relative URL `src="images/myimage.jpg"`.

The resulting url will be: `https://example.com/items/images/myimage.jpg`. This is because, when you don't put `/` before `images` in `src="images/myimage.jpg"`, you are telling the browser that the `images` folder is located in the same directory as the `menu.html` file.

Imagine, inside `example.com` folder, has `items` folder, inside `items` folder has both `images` folder and `menu.html` file.

So it will change from `https://example.com/items/menu.html` to `https://example.com/items/images/myimage.jpg` because `images` folder and `menu.html` are on the same level when you don't put `/` before `images`. That's it!

(2) Relative URLs with absolute path = URL that specify the complete path starting from the root directory of the website.

Example, you are on `https://example.com/items/menu.html` again.

You have an `images` folder at the root directory of the website. P/s: Root directory is `https://example.com/`.

You want to link to an image file in root folder, you would use the relative URL with absolute path `src="/images/myimage.jpg"`. Notice that it has `/` before `images` to specify that it will be relative to root directory.

The resulting url will be: `https://example.com/images/myimage.jpg`. It will change from `https://example.com/items/menu.html` to `https://example.com/images/myimage.jpg` because `images` folder are on the root directory. That's it!

(3) Long story short,

You are on `https://example.com/items/menu.html`.

If you use `src="images/myimage.jpg"`,
resulting URL will be `https://example.com/items/images/myimage.jpg`.

If you use `src="/images/myimage.jpg"`,
resulting URL will be `https://example.com/images/myimage.jpg`.