# htaccess: Why doesn't this work?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I get a 404 error page when I try the following rule in htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^Test\?service=(.*) test.php?foo=$1 [NC,L]
```

How come?

I know it's preferable to use something like **^Test/(.*) test.php?foo=$1 [NC,L]** instead, but in this case I'd rather like it the way I stated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what address are you typing into your browser? I expect it does not match your regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) does only check the [URL path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904046/absolute-urls-relative-urls-and/904066#904066). But the query (the part from the first `?` up to the first `#`) is not part of the URL path. That can only be checked with the [`RewriteCond` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^service=(.*)
RewriteRule ^Test$ test.php?foo=%1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: By the way, how do I append multiple parameters?

Comment: @Ivarska: Can you give an example?

Comment: @Gumbo: ex: Test?x=foo&y=bar >>> qwe.php?a=Test&b=foo&c=bar

Comment: Set the QSA flag and the original query is appended to the new one.