# javascript drop-down menu: how to link to different sites?

Tags: javascript, html, menu, hyperlink, drop-down-menu

I'm a college student trying to create a drop-down menu for my professor. Since I don't have any programming background, I found a program called ["SoThink DHTML"](http://www.sothink.com/product/dhtmlmenu/) that generated a code for me, but there are some errors within that I don't know how to fix.

The menu, overall, should have tabs to "Home," "Research" (3 subtabs: "Research Projects," "Systems and Approaches," and "Images and Movies"), "Publications, "Lab Members," "Links," and "Contact Us." The automatically generated code, however, doesn't provide links to some of these titles, and I was wondering how can I insert the links manually?

How can I insert the paths so that they do not refer to specific files, but are more flexible when I move the folder containing the website?

I hope that this makes some sense..

Thank you so much for your help in advance!!

```
stm_bm(["menu1c53",960,"","blank.gif",0,"","",1,0,250,0,1000,1,0,0,"","100%",0,0,1,2,"default","hand","",1,25],this);
stm_bp("p0",[0,4,0,0,0,0,0,15,100,"",-2,"",-2,50,0,0,"#999999","transparent","line1.gif",3,0,0,"#000000"]);
stm_ai("p0i0",[0,"Home","","",-1,-1,0,"","_self","","","","",0,0,0,"","",0,0,0,1,1,"#E6EFF9",1,"#E6EFF9",1,"","line2.gif",1,3,0,0,"#E6EFF9","#000000","#426b10","#426b10","bold 9pt Verdana","bold 9pt Verdana",0,0,"","line2.gif","","line2.gif",2,2,42],100,0);
stm_aix("p0i1","p0i0",[0,"Research","","",-1,-1,0,"","_self","","","","",0,0,0,"arrow1.gif","arrow2.gif",15,9],100,0);
stm_bp("p1",[1,4,0,-3,6,0,5,0,100,"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.RandomDissolve(,enabled=0,Duration=0.30)",12,"",-2,80,0,0,"#999999","#beeb94","",3,0,0,"#CCCCCC","",-1,-1,0,"transparent","",3,"",-1,-1,0,"transparent","",3,"line3.gif",-1,-1,0,"transparent","line3.gif",3,"",-1,-1,0,"transparent","",3,"","","","",1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]);
stm_ai("p1i0",[0,"Research Projects","","",-1,-1,0,"./Research_Projects.html","_self","","","","",5,1,0,"","",0,0,0,0,1,"#E6EFF9",1,"#edf9e1",0,"","",3,3,0,0,"#E6EFF9","#000000","#426b10","#426b10","7pt Verdana","7pt Verdana",0,0,"","","","",0,0,0],0,20);
stm_aix("p1i1","p1i0",[0,"Systems and Approaches","","",-1,-1,0,"./Systems_and_Approaches.html"],0,20);
stm_aix("p1i2","p1i0",[0,"Images and Movies","","",-1,-1,0,"./Images_and_Movies.html"],0,20);
stm_mc("p1",[7,"#1E1E1E",1,2,"",3]);
stm_ep();
stm_aix("p0i2","p0i0",[0,"Publications","","",-1,-1,0,"#"],100,0);
stm_aix("p0i3","p0i2",[0,"Lab Members"],100,0);
stm_aix("p0i4","p0i2",[0,"Links"],100,0);
stm_aix("p0i5","p0i2",[0,"Contact Us"],100,0);
stm_ep();
stm_em();
```

Comment: I don't see the java connection here

Comment: sorry? I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Skaff: She's confusing [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) with [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29). I edited the tags.

Comment: I really don't know what to do...

Comment: Thank you for editing the question! I would really appreciate some help on this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using relative urls, which find a file based on the current location. Therefore they mean different things when the file containing the urls is in different places.

```
../../public/img/logo.gif
```

absolute urls start from the root of the website, which means you can move the file containing them anywhere and it will still refer to the same location.

```
http://www.somedomain.com/en/public/img/logo.gif
```

[more on the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904046/absolute-urls-relative-urls-and) (warning, get technical).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I would prefer to use relative URL... but idk how to put the URL in! :(

Comment: I can't be sure because I haven't used the software. You could go through the code you posted and replace all the urls (most have file extensions in your case) with the absolute equivalent.

Comment: I did that, but it still doesn't work. For things like: stm_aix("p0i2","p0i0",[0,"Publications","","",-1,-1,0,"#"],100,0);
there isn't even a place to put the absolute URL.