# PHP web app is unsecure while I already used pashword hash for password protection

Tags: php, mysql

I made a Customer relationship manager in php for one of my clients and I am facing issue of unsecurity in some of it pages due to which it broke the menu and it does not work properly. Using google sxtension when I allow it to proceed unsecure the menu start working properly. I used password hash for password protection.
When I click the below in chrome extension it start working properly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPdq3.png)

Comment: Is this a https issue?

Comment: htttp or htttps in url ?

Comment: I don't know about it, but SSL is already installed on the domain.

Comment: https domain it is

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I think the title explains it very clearly that "my web app is giving unsecure error in browser after uploading it to the hosting evenn I used password hash for protection of passwords"

Comment: The error says: "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://bestpoolcompany.com/pool-crm/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

Comment: That is the opposite of very clearly. Password hash has nothing to do with this.

Comment: can you post httpaccess file ?

Comment: Yes I did a mistake and place it outside of head, but still I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about the Secure Socket Layer (SSL)?

Make sure all your links are ***https***://directory/folder/file.ext and not ***http***://directory/folder/file.ext

If you want the links to work with both a secure and non-secure web site, you can start your links with just the slashes and no protocol name and colon. *//directory/folder/file.ext*

Edit: OPs problem had to do with `The Protocol-relative URL` [Are protocol-relative URLs relative URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581445/are-protocol-relative-urls-relative-urls)

More information: https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Comment: This could be the right answer to OP's question, but you should improve the quality.

Comment: Marked this answer as correct, we have to make all that cdn link as //cdn..... without HTTP or https.

Answer (score 0):

You could just have the CDN package downloaded and stored locally in your website's folder, then include it locally.