# getting data from controller in error function of jquery ajax -- Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a jquery ajax script like following

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Main/receive", // the method we are calling
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'p':$("#txtname").val() }),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                alert('Yay! It worked!');
                // Or if you are returning something

            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert('Oh no zzzz:('+result.responseText);
            }
        });
```

And I am calling to Controller action method. The data is sending to the controller's action method and I am also receiving data from the controller. But the data that I am receiving is inside the error function of jquery ajax.

I want it to be inside the success function.

Why my success function is not getting called.

Following is my controller's action method,

```
   [HttpPost]
    public string receive(string p)
    {
        ViewBag.name = p;
        return p;

    }
```

Comment: Because you have specified that the return type is json (i.e. `dataType: "json",`). Change the server method to `return Json(p);` But there are lots or other potential errors in your code so I will post an answer later.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks, please don't forget to post answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you have specified that the returned data type be json (in the line `dataType: "json",`) but you method returns text. You have 2 options.

1. Change the controller method to return json using `return Json(p);`
2. Change the ajax option to `dataType: "text",` or just omit it

However you can improve your script as noted below

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '@Url.Action("receive", "Main")', // don't hardcode url's
  data: { p: $("#txtname").val() }, // no need to stringify (delete the contentType: option)
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (result) {
      alert('Yay! It worked!');
  },
  error: function (result) {
      alert('Oh no zzzz:('+result.responseText);
  }
});
```

or even simpler

```
$.post('@Url.Action("receive", "Main")', { p: $("#txtname").val() }, function(result) {
    alert('Yay! It worked!');
}).fail(function(result) {
    alert('Oh no zzzz:('+result.responseText);
});
```

Notes: You should always use `@Url.Action()` to generate the correct urls, and it is not necessary in this case to stringify the data (but you need to remove the `contentType:` line so it used the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`)

In addition, this is not strictly a POST (your not changing data on the server - but I assume this is just for testing). And there is no point in the line `ViewBag.name = p;` - it does nothing in your context, and as soon as you return from the method, `ViewBag` is lost anyway.

Comment: I had a typo in the `error` line - see edit, but that error does not make sense (I tested the code in my project and it works fine). I'll see if I can find some info on that error

Comment: I have asked a new question. can you please check it out?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30420765/asp-net-mvc-model-example-is-correct-or-incorrect

Answer (score 0):

try to change your controller code as follows

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult List(string p)
    {
       ViewBag.name = p;
       return Json(ViewBag);
    }
```

Comment: it's giving error. can not convert p string to type object

Answer (score 0):

Your controller method should look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult receive(string p)
{
   return Json(p);
}
```