# Asp.net MVC Model example is correct or incorrect

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have asp.net MVC application.

And I have a main page (View).

The data in the view contains: news headlines, weather update, sports section.

So for this I have created a model.

Model contains all the requirements: news headlines (list of class type News), weather (string weather), sports section (list of class SportSection)

So my model class is something like this

```
public class Main
{
     public List<News> news=new List<News>();
     public List<SportSection> results=new List<SportSection>()
     public string weather;
}
```

And I am populating my data in Controller. And sending my model to view in Controller's action method like this

```
 Models.Main m=new Models.Main()
 ...
 ...
 ...

 return View(m);
```

I need to know, my understanding of Asp.net MVC Models is correct as it is shown in example above?

Comment: Depends, what you mean by **correct**?

Comment: I meant, according to the example in the question I need to know that my use of Model is not breaking any norms of MVC architecture? It's not outlandish in any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **Model** respect the purpose for keeping data for transport and don't have behaviour.

Instead of *fields* you have to use *properties* and you can respect naming convention from C#.

```
public class Main
{
     public List<News> News { get; set; }
     public List<SportSection> Results { get; set; }
     public string Weather { get; set; }

    public Main()
    {
        News=new List<News>();
        Results=new List<SportSection>()
    }
}
```

**Note:** Also there is a **ViewModel** and the role of him is to keep only relevant data, so if you don't need some properties you need to remove them (i.e. if the `Weather` is not needed in your View, remove the `Weather` property)