# Confused with /app_name/page or app_name/page

Tags: python, django

I am confused that whether should I start a path starting with `/` or not? For example, here is one method from my `views.py` in django:

```
@login_required
def add_page(request,category_name_slug=None):
    # check for post method
    print category_name_slug
    try:
        cat = Category.objects.get(slug = category_name_slug)
    except Exception, e:
        cat = None


    if request.method == 'POST':
        print "sjhdfkjsdhkfhjs"
        # means you submitted the form.
        form = PageForm(request.POST)
        a = form.is_valid()
        if a:
            if cat:
                page = form.save(commit = False)
                page.category = cat
                page.views = 0
                page.save()
                print "sdjhfjshk"
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/rango/category/' + category_name_slug + '/')
        else:
            print form.errors

    else:
        form = PageForm()

    context_dict = {'form' : form,'category' : cat, 'slug': category_name_slug}

    return render(request,'rango/add_page.html', context_dict)
```

In the render line

> return render(request,'rango/add_page.html', context_dict)

the line is not started with `/`. But, in case of following line:

> return HttpResponseRedirect('/rango/category/' + category_name_slug + '/')

I have to start with `/`. Please explain me when should I use '/' and when not.

Comment: The short answer is that one is a relative path and the other is absolute.

Comment: Which one should be used where?

Comment: That depends if you want to go to yoursite.com/rango (absolute) or yoursite.com/current/page/rango (relative)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `render` function in django, the second argument is the template name.

The string you specify there is used relative to the `TEMPLATES` settings you've defined in your settings.py. It tells django where the template file is located. This is why you don't start the template name with '/' in `render()`

Whereas, `HttpResponseRedirect` directly asks for the URL to redirect. It is upto you whether you should add '/' to it before the string.

When the supplied URL starts with '/', no matter where you redirect from, the user is taken to the exact path relative the the website root.

For example, if the user is at http://127.0.0.1:8000/some/other/page/ and you use the following to redirect user:

> return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard/')

The user will be redirected to http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/

If the URL does not start with '/', the url is just appended to the url from which user is visiting.
In this case:

> return HttpResponseRedirect('dashboard/')

User will be taken to http://127.0.0.1:8000/some/other/page/dashboard/

Comment: so, the first one is relative and second one is absolute path?

Comment: No, both of them are relative URLs. Urls which do not start with `http://` or `https://` are relative urls.

Comment: @learner, See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/904066/4726598 for better understanding :)