# "Page not found (404)" when clicking on follow or unfollow button

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

urls.py

```
"""stratinum URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.conf.urls import url, include
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

from imagec import views as imagec_views
from contact import views as contact_views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', imagec_views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^about/$', imagec_views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^detail/$', imagec_views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^profile/$', imagec_views.userProfile, name='profile'),
    url(r'^create_form/$', imagec_views.create_form, name='create_form'),
    url(r'^contact/$', contact_views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^userProfile/$', contact_views.contact, name='userProfile'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
    url('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', namespace='auth')),
    url(r'^$', imagec_views.ListaFollow, name="lista_follow"),
    url(r'^add_follow/(?P<id>\d{1,})/$', imagec_views.AddFollow, name='add_follow'),
    url(r'^remove_follow/(?P<id>\d{1,})/$', imagec_views.RemoveFollow, name='remove_follow')

]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .forms import AlbumForm
from .models import Album


from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseForbidden

IMAGE_FILE_TYPES = ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    context = {}
    template = 'home.html'
    return render(request, template, context)

def about(request):
    context = {}
    template = 'about.html'
    return render(request, template, context)

@login_required()
def userProfile(request):
    user = request.user
    context = {'user': user}
    template = 'profile.html'
    return render(request, template, context)



def create_form(request):
        form = AlbumForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            album = form.save(commit=False)
            album.user = request.user
            album.image= request.FILES['image']
            file_type = album.image.url.split('.')[-1]
            file_type = file_type.lower()
            if file_type not in IMAGE_FILE_TYPES:
                context = {
                    'album': album,
                    'form': form,
                    'error_message': 'Image file must be PNG, JPG, or JPEG',
                }
                return render(request, 'detail.html', context)
            album.save()
            return render(request, 'create_form.html', {'album': album})
        context = {
            "form": form,
        }
        return render(request, 'create_form.html', context)

def detail(request):
        user = request.user
        #album = get_object_or_404(Album, pk=id)
        return render(request, 'detail.html', {'user': user})


from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import MyUser

from django.views.generic import TemplateView,View
from django.db.models import Q
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from . import models
#from imagec.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission, User


class ListaFollow(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'lista_follow.html'
    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(ListaFollow,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['all'] = MyUser.objects.all()
        context['me'] = User.objects.get(username=self.request.user)
        context['notme'] = MyUser.objects.filter(follow__username=self.request.user)
        context['notfollow'] = MyUser.objects.filter(~Q(follow__username=self.request.user))
        return context

class AddFollow(View):
    def get(self,request, id):
        me=models.MyUser.objects.get(username=request.user)
        followed = models.MyUser.objects.get(id=id) #el wey
        me.follow.add(followed)
        return redirect(reverse('imagec/about.html'))

class RemoveFollow(View):
    def get(self,request, id):
        me=models.MyUser.objects.get(username=request.user) #instancia del usuario con el id que quiero crear
        followed = models.MyUser.objects.get(id=id)
        me.follow.remove(followed) #creo el usuario con mi nombre y la relacion
        return redirect(reverse('imagec/about.html'))
```

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission, User

from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(default='description default text')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Album(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
    image = models.FileField()


class MyUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    follow = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

about.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{%  block   content %}
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Profile</h1>
    <p>Username: {{ user }}</p>
    <p>Email: {{ user.email }}</p>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Upload"/></p>

</div>
<table>
<tr>
<th colspan="3"> @ {{ user }}</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<span> Follows </span>
</td>
</tr>


<td>{{follow}} <a href="add_follow/{{user.id}}">
    <button>Follow</button></a></td>
<td>{{follow}} <a href="remove_follow/{{user.id}}">
    <button>Unfollow</button></a></td>
</a>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<span> Unfollows </span>
</td>
</tr>


</table>
</body>

{%  endblock    %}
```

When I run this code I will get error as:

> "Not Found: /about/add_follow/1
>   [22/Apr/2017 07:26:25] "GET /about/add_follow/1 HTTP/1.1" 404 6063"

in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This happening because you are using relative url to create a link to the follow/unfollow page. To fix this, you can either make it an absolute url or use django's url reverser.

Making the link absolute:

```
<td>{{follow}} <a href="/add_follow/{{user.id}}">
    <button>Follow</button></a></td>
<td>{{follow}} <a href="/remove_follow/{{user.id}}">
    <button>Unfollow</button></a></td>
```

Making use of the [url tempalte tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

```
<td>{{follow}} <a href="{% url 'add_follow' id=user.id %}">
    <button>Follow</button></a></td>
<td>{{follow}} <a href="{% url 'remove_follow' id=user.id %}">
    <button>Unfollow</button></a></td>
```

Read about [Absolute and Relative urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904046/absolute-urls-relative-urls-and)

Comment: By adding above code i m getting new error as" TypeError at /add_follow/1/

__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Comment: this is happening because you your url conf is incorrect. when using class-based-views, you have to call `.as_view()` on the View. change urls to `imagec_views.AddFollow.as_view()`

Comment: for this i m getting error as "MultipleObjectsReturned at /add_follow/1/

get() returned more than one Album -- it returned 5!"

Comment: It means you are not querying on a unique field, make your query either returns one object at max, not more than that.

Comment: umm.... the `id` field is a unique field as it is set as primary key in django, you should query on that field.

Comment: i m getting error as "DoesNotExist at /add_follow/1/

Album matching query does not exist."

Comment: i m getting error in views.py for this line  "me=models.Album.objects.get(username=request.user)" as Album matching query does not exist.

Comment: Which means there is no album which has a user which you queried for. The error will disappear if you have an album object with the queried user.